# How can I loop through dynamic URLs in Django 4?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

**The problem:**
I recently published a site on Python Anywhere and had to go through the tedious process of changing all of the page URLs I had set through my SQLite database. All of the URLs were broken since the root had changed from the local port to "username.pythonanywhere.com".

I had no problem doing this, but I realized that in order to do local development I would need to change the URLs in the database *back* to their local port paths. This is obviously why we use dynamic URLs. However, the URLs that were hard coded were like that because I was using a **for** loop on the rendered html page to loop through those static URLs in my database.

**My question is**, how can I use dynamic URLs `{% url app:template %}` in a for loop? Ideally, I would like to have a field in my database that contains the `app:template` information such that I can loop through all the projects in my database and link them dynamically by grabbing the info from that field.

**I have tried** creating a new CharField in models.py with a string value for `{% url app:template %}`, hoping that it would work with the templating language of `href="{{ project.href_str}}"`, but this doesn't seem to work. I have tried this method in various combinations of field string values and templating language values. I also tried this method of using the templating language as a string by adding a dictionary to my views.py return statement, with the difference of calling the keys in `href="{{ project_urls.appname }}"`. No luck here either.

Just for the record, I have tried the dynamic URLs that I want outside of loops and they work perfectly, so I don't think this is a problem with the url mapping itself.

**Here's the HTML:**
In my database, `project.href_str` has a value of {% url 'calculator:calculator' %}

```
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">

      {% if project.href_str %}
      <a href="{{ project.href_str }}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2" style="">
      </a>

      {% else %}
        <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2" width="500" height="500">

      {% endif %}

      <h3 class="">{{ project.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ project.description }}</p>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you should better use a [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) for this. In your template, you can pass a variable to the [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) resolver {% url 'app:view' project.href %}. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. All I needed to do was reference the model field without any templating language.

`<a href="{% url project.href_str %}" target="_blank">` where project.href_str is a CharField works perfectly fine. My problem was assuming it needed {{}} or something extra.

```
{% for project in projects %}
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">

      {% if project.href %}
      <a href="{% url project.href_str %}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2" style="">
      </a>

      {% else %}
        <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2" width="500" height="500">

      {% endif %}

      <h3 class="">{{ project.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ project.description }}</p>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```